# Trouble loading C library in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mex, loadlibrary

I'm trying to use MATLAB to control a stepper motor using a Phidget 1063_1 controller. Phidgets provides libraries and sample programs for their devices and I'm trying to run their example stepper motor program. The program loads a C library (something I have no experience with in MATLAB). This is the program I'm trying to run:

```
function stepper

loadphidget21;

stepperHandle = libpointer('int32Ptr');
calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_create', stepperHandle);
calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidget_open', stepperHandle, -1);

valPtr = libpointer('int64Ptr', 0);

if calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidget_waitForAttachment', stepperHandle, 2500) == 0
    disp('Opened Stepper');

    t = timer('TimerFcn','disp(''waiting...'')', 'StartDelay', 1.0);

    %set parameters for stepper motor in index 0 (velocity, acceleration, current)
    %these values were set basd on some testing based on a 1063 and a stepper motor I had here to test with
    %might need to modify these values for your particular case
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setVelocityLimit', stepperHandle, 0, 6200);
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setAcceleration', stepperHandle, 0, 87543);
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setCurrentLimit', stepperHandle, 0, 0.26);

    %IMPORTANT: If you are using a 1062, delete this line.  This command is only for the 1063 Bipolar stepper controller
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setCurrentPosition', stepperHandle, 0, 0);

    start(t);
    wait(t);

    disp('Engage Motor 0');

    %engage the stepper motor in index 0
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setEngaged', stepperHandle, 0, 1);
    start(t);
    wait(t);

    currPosition=0;
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_getCurrentPosition', stepperHandle, 0, valPtr);
    currPosition = get(valPtr, 'Value');

    disp('Move to 20000');

    %set motor to position 1 (20000)
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setTargetPosition', stepperHandle, 0, 20000);

    %wait for motor to arrive
    while currPosition < 20000
        calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_getCurrentPosition', stepperHandle, 0, valPtr);
        currPosition = get(valPtr, 'Value');
    end
    disp('Motor reached target');

    start(t);
    wait(t);

    disp('Move to 0');

    %set motor to position 2 (0)
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setTargetPosition', stepperHandle, 0, 0);

    %wait for motor to arrive
    while currPosition > 0
        calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_getCurrentPosition', stepperHandle, 0, valPtr);
        currPosition = get(valPtr, 'Value');
    end
    disp('Motor reached target');

    disp('Disengage Motor 0');

    %disengage the stepper motor in index 0
    calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidgetStepper_setEngaged', stepperHandle, 0, 0);
    start(t);
    wait(t);
else
    disp('Could Not Open Stepper');
end

disp('Closing Stepper');
% clean up
calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidget_close', stepperHandle);
calllib('phidget21', 'CPhidget_delete', stepperHandle);

disp('Closed Stepper');
```

When I run it I get the following errors:

```
>> stepper
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in loadlibrary>getLoadlibraryCompilerConfiguration (line 527)



Error in loadlibrary (line 263)



Error in loadphidget21 (line 12)
            [notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary('phidget21', 'phidget21Matlab_Windows_x64.h');

Error in stepper (line 3)
loadphidget21;
```

In some other threads, people have said that this happens when a C compiler has not been configured for MATLAB and that configuring a compiler for mex should solve this problem. I'm having trouble with this as well:

```
>> mex -setup
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit  http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/win64.html.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the very last line of your error message:

> *No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit  http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/win64.html.*

You currently have no compiler that is compatible with R2015 installed on your system.  Visit that link for your options.  You need to obtain a compatible compiler in order to get your code working.

Also, when you visit that MathWorks page, a disclaimer is shown for your platform:

> For the 64-bit Windows platform, a C compiler is not supplied with MATLAB. A free download is available that is suitable for most users:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

You are trying to compile C code and MATLAB does not come shipped with a C compiler.  Downloading the Microsoft SDK Version 7.1 with NET Framework 4 is the easiest solution to get your code to compile.  As such, download the SDK from the above link from Microsoft, re-setup `mex` and try your code again.

Comment: Thanks. I had gone through the installation process Windows SDK and NET framework 4 but I didn't pay close attention to it. The win SDK installation had actually failed but I just clicked "finish" and moved on.
For anyone who is having trouble installing win SDK, try uninstalling all Visual C++ 2010 Resdistributables and reinstall.

Comment: @Hadi - Oops! Glad you figured it out.  Good luck!